# Cannot update pod due to dependencies in React Native module

Tags: ios, react-native, dependencies, cocoapods, snowplow

I am trying to update SnowplowTracker of our app. I changed the version of SnowplowTracker on my PodFile:

```
pod 'SnowplowTracker', '~> 1.3'
```

However I am getting this error when I run my pod install:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "SnowplowTracker":
  In Podfile:
    RNVideo (from `../node_modules/react-native-video`) was resolved to 3.9.2, which depends on
      MCTracker (~> 1.1.0) was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
        SnowplowTracker (= 1.1.4)

    SnowplowTracker (~> 1.3)

Specs satisfying the `SnowplowTracker (~> 1.3), SnowplowTracker (= 1.1.4)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like the newer version requires higher deployment target so you'll need to specify minimum ios version required for the update in podfile. If it still fails, try removing podlock and reinstall. Last options would be to pod repo update and then pod install (in case pod does not recognize updated version)

Comment: Actually the RNVideo needed to update its pods to the latest version too. So the React Native developer of the company is working on it. Thank you.